# Changing the width of a knob on a JSlider

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jslider

Ok, so I have searched google for a while now to see if I can find the answer to this but no dice. Maybe I am just searching for the wrong thing but this is what I want to know:

How do you change the width of the actual Knob on the JSlider component? NOT how to change the width of the JSlider.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```
   BasicSliderUI sliderUI = new javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSliderUI(jTimeSlider){
        protected Dimension getThumbSize() {
              return new Dimension(15, 20);
          }
      };
    jTimeSlider.setUI(sliderUI);
```

where dimension width is the width of the knob.

Comment: not recommended to set a per-instance ui: a) it will not survive changing the LAF b) extending basic sure looks strange in an application using another LAF